# Parsing XML data with python - how to capture everything in a more pythonic way?

Tags: python, xml, loops

The aim is to capture all data in an xml file. Once captured, im comparing it to a reference xml file to ensure nothing has changed and to then tell you what the differences are.

What i wrote works for what I need, but is very cumbersome and a bit messy! Is there a better way to iterate through all items at all depths of an xml file? The solution just has to be robust to capture everything.

Currently, iterating like I have below uses too may layers of iteration with try/except that is very ugly!

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def xml_iter(file):
    
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    namespaces = {}

    List = []
    Parent = []
    for elem in root:
        for i in elem:
            try:
                i = i.text.strip()
                List.append(i)
            except:
                pass
     
            for j in i:
                try:
                    j = j.text.strip()
                    List.append(j)
                except:
                    pass
  
                for k in j:
                    try:
                        k = k.text.strip()
                        List.append(k)
                    except:
                        pass
    return (List)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User [Element.iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter). It iterates recursively over all the sub-trees.

For your case, it would be something like:

```
dict_list = []
text_list = []
for node in root.iter():
    dict_list.append(node.attrib) # adds to list, the dictionary of attrib
    text_list.append(node.text)

 

# do the same for other file and compare dictionaries/strings in corresponding lists.
```

You can look at this official [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for examples.

Comment: Thanks! That's far cleaner than what I used! For some reason, the XML file im parsing has no attributes when I look at dict.list. However, when I use node.tag, it gets me the element name. Is there a way to get the tree address from an element, instead of just the element? My sub-trees are quite deep, so an element name is almost impossible to find!!

Comment: It is possible that there are no attributes at all in your XML. An example given in the linked tutorial:
<country name="Singapore">
      <rank>4</rank>
Here, for the first line node.tag is  "country";  node.attrib is {"name":"Singapore"} and node.text is null. 
For the second line, node.tag is "rank" and node.text is 4 and node.attrib is null.

Think of HTML while thinking of what is tag, attribute and text.
Then look at "Finding interesting elements" section of  [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for your usecase.